# Url absoluta desde _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy desarrollando una página en la cual doy de alta imágenes y PDF's, el problema es que quiero poner por ejemplo cuando yo seleccione un PDF para verlo la url me salga con la ruta completa por decirlo `www.ejemplo.com/home/pdf/ejemplo.pdf`, hasta ahora las imágenes se guardan con la siguiente ruta `../Home/Imagenes/` o `../Home/PDF/`,  pero al platicarlo con algunos compañeros cuando la página este en el servidor debe de mostrar la ruta completa osea el protocolo, el servidor y la ruta. 
La verdad es que no tengo idea de como hacerlo, estuve investigando pero no encontré algo que me pudiera ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Extraído de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2070012/3613462

Puedes hacer una clase a modo de Helper que reutilices en todo el sistema:

```
public static string ResolveServerUrl(string serverUrl, bool forceHttps)
{
    if (serverUrl.IndexOf("://") > -1)
        return serverUrl;

    string nuevaUrl = serverUrl;
    Uri originalUri = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
    nuevaUrl = (forceHttps ? "https" : originalUri.Scheme) +
        "://" + originalUri.Authority + nuevaUrl;
    return nuevaUrl;
}
```

La utilizas de esta manera:

```
ResolveServerUrl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/image1.gif"),false))
```

El resultado:

```
http://www.yourdomainname.com/images/image1.gif
```

> "estuve investigando pero no encontré algo que me pudiera ayudar."

Para encontrar este ejemplo, éstas fueron las palabras en el buscador de https://www.ecosia.org/ Hay que ser ecológicos :D ¡Vamos reforestando nuestro planeta en nuestro día a día!

> "aspnet mvc get full url"

Comment: Y esto como lo podría usar en una vista `ResolveServerUrl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/image1.gif"),false))` ?